# Calendar Management System for SaaS products

Tags: calendar, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I'm looking for a solution to help me do calendar management in my system (something like Calendar as a Service).

Some of the features that I would need are

1. Ability to create a calendar for every user in my system.
2. Allow everyone to set their availability and Off Days. They should also be able to change the availability for a specific day.
3. Ability for the system to book a timeslot on any of the user's calendars.
4. Ability to check conflicts before booking a slot.
5. Ability to get notified via Webhooks whenever someone cancels the already booked slots.

I don't need a UI. I can use any readily available Calendar UI Component. All I need is a service that can provide APIs to manage multiple calendars (one of each user in my system).

I've explored Calendly, but it requires every user within my system to have an account on Calendly as well. So it's not going to work for me.

Currently, I'm exploring Calendso, but I would appreciate it if you could share any other services you are familiar with that I should explore for this use case.